# Iterate over all the elements in a std::multimap with the same key

Tags: c++, std, multimap

I want to add objects so a multi-map and some should have the same key how can I get access to all the elements which the same key?

Can I do a ranged fore lope over only the specific keys or something similar?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap -> Lookup -> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range. Nobody knows all c++ by heart. You need to get used to look things up. I recommend cppreference.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number sorry I just have h hard time understanding the cpprefrense simtimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) member, and wrap that in a [`ranges::subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange/subrange) to range-for over it.

```
auto range = map.equal_range(key); 
for (auto & [_, value] : std::ranges::subrange(range.first, range.second)) {
    // ...
}
```

When ranged-for was being proposed, it was considered to let `std::pair<iter, iter>` be directly iterated over, but that was rejected as potentially dangerous.

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/576f2b1c0e366630)